# Python exception handling - avoid writing 30+ try except blocks

Tags: python, dictionary, exception

I have a dictionary which is populated from xml. Dictionary has a lot of key-value pairs. I have to populate a custom object with values from that dictionary. I want to catch exception if one key in dictionary is not present or the value is not the expected type, log which key and continue execution. Is there a better way than surrounding each line with try expect block. To be specific I want to avoid this syntax, it does what I need, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient solution:

```
try:
    my_object.prop1 = dictionary['key1']
except Exception as e:
    log.write('key1')

try:
    my_object.prop2 = dictionary['key2']
except Exception as e:
    log.write('key2')

try:
    my_object.prop3 = dictionary['key3']
except Exception as e:
    log.write('key3')

....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it programmatically.

```
props_keys = {
    'prop1': 'key1'
    'prop2': 'key2',
    'prop3': 'key3'
}

for prop, key in props_keys.iteritems():
    try:
        setattr(myobj, prop, mydict[key])
    except KeyError:
        log(key)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for key, prop in [('key1', 'prop1'), ('key2', 'prop2'), ('key3', 'prop3')]:
    try:
        setattr(my_object, prop, dictionary[key])
    except KeyError:
        log.write(key)
```

Note that I'm also using `KeyError` here; try to keep your caught exceptions as specific as possible. If `prop1` may raise its own errors, add that to the list of expected errors.

Comment: I would replace *key* by *key, prop* in the *for* statement to avoid the  indexing, which is not exactly self-explaining.

Comment: Yes, true, a valid improvement.